# Set cache for each user in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, caching

I using CodeIgniter 3.1.5  which each user can register and login in own his profile, I have user_id in session, I want using cache (web cache, or cache driver not different) for each one And I don't want using query_string, how can create cache file for each user ?

Comment: Have you considered sessions?

Comment: sure , but it not enough